# Spotify: find out which track is currently playing

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I'm looking for a way to find the track a user is currently playing (if any). Curiously, there doesn't seem to be any provision for this in libspotify.

I'm not even sure that this functionality is possible at all. Spotify allows a user (account) to play music from only a single device at a time. However, I do not know whether they keep track only of the device or the track in addition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listening history data by user (spotify)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459967/listening-history-data-by-user-spotify)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459967/listening-history-data-by-user-spotify/, which is in itself a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456370/how-to-get-the-latest-played-spotify-songs